# Dynamically Loading Livewire Components Based on Select Element?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working on a reporting module in a Laravel project, which uses Livewire for the interactive components. Specifically, I have a ReportManager Livewire component, responsible for managing several other report classes (livewire components that ecapsulate all the logic and template for a single report). These components are registered in an array within the ReportManager like so:

```php
$registeredReports = [
    ReportDailyExtensionStats::class,
    ReportAgentWeeklyStats::class,
    // Additional future reports will be registered here
];
```

In my Blade template, I have a `<select>` element that should dictate which of these report components to load. The Blade code is as follows:

```php
<select wire:model="selectedReport" wire:change="displayReport" class="...">
    @foreach($reports as $className => $metadata)
        <option value="{{ $className }}"> {{ $metadata['name'] }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>

@if($selectedReport === 'ReportDailyExtensionStats')
    @livewire('ReportDailyExtensionStats')
@elseif($selectedReport === 'ReportAgentWeeklyStats')
    @livewire('ReportAgentWeeklyStats')
@endif
```

The challenge I'm facing is with the dynamic loading of Livewire components based on the selected value. I currently have to use a set of `@if` and `@elseif` Blade directives to load the correct component. If I simply use `@livewire($selectedReport)`, it works on the initial render but does not update when the value of the `<select>` changes.

Is there a more elegant way to dynamically load these Livewire components without having to explicitly define each one in Blade, effectively registering them twice?

Comment: share the livewire component class code